# Spring mvc portlet @sessionAtribute

Tags: spring-mvc, annotations, javabeans, portlet

Hello would need a little help.

I'm working with Spring and portlets, my problem is that I have 2 tabs handled by two different controller with 2 beans. What I need is to display data from the bean of the first controller in the render phase of the second controller.

I try to do as follows:

This is the controller for the first tab where I collect the necessary values ​​and generated a request with them.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(ServletContextKeys.SC_VIEW_MODE)
//This is my bean session
@SessionAttributes(salarioBean)
public class AltaSalarioFSOPortletController extends BaseController {

private SalarioBean salarioBean;

//With this method generated the request to display the data in the other controller jsp
@RequestMapping(params = ACTION_CAMBIA_TAB)
public final String doRenderTab(@ModelAttribute(value = "SalarioBean") SalarioBean salario, Errors errors, RenderRequest renderrequest, PortletSession portletSession) {

    //retrieve the bean managed by Spring in session
    SalarioBean salarioSessionBean = (SalarioBean) portletSession.getAttribute(salarioBean);

    ImputacionBean imputacionBean = new ImputacionBean();
    ....Insert data on imputacionBean

    //generated the request to display data in jsp handled by another controller
    renderrequest.setAttribute(imputacionBean,imputacionBean);

    //redirected to jsp
    return jsp_tab2;
}
```

With this controller with it to display data in jsp, but my problem comes when trying to generate the same data when click-on the other tab. So I try to do with this method render in another controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(ServletContextKeys.SC_VIEW_MODE)
@SessionAttributes(imputacionBean)
public class AsociarCostesSalarioAlumnoPortletController extends BaseController {

private ImputacionBean imputacionBean;

@RequestMapping(params = ACTION_ASOC_COSTES_SALARIO)
public final String doRender(@ModelAttribute(value = "ImputacionBean") ImputacionBean imputacionSalarioAlumno,Errors errors, RenderRequest renderrequest,SessionStatus status) {

    justifSessionBean = (SalarioBean) renderrequest.getPortletSession().getAttribute(salarioBean);

    ImputacionBean imp=(ImputacionBean) justifSessionBean.getImputaciones().get(0);

renderrequest.getPortletSession().setAttribute(imputacionBean,imp);

    setJustificanteAsociarCostesSalarioAlumno(imp);

    setRequestParameters(renderrequest, imp);

    return jsp_tab2;
}

@Override
public final void setRequestParameters(RenderRequest renderrequest, Object object) {

    ImputacionBean imputacionSalarioAlumno = (ImputacionBean) object;

    renderrequest.setAttribute(imputacionBean, imputacionSalarioAlumno);

      renderrequest.getPortletSession().setAttribute(imputacionBean,imputacionSalarioAlumno);
}

public final void setJustificanteAsociarCostesSalarioAlumno(ImputacionBean imputacionSalario) {
    this.imputacionBean = imputacionSalario;
}
```

The first time the bean that handles spring is object empty. My question is: how I can set the session bean that handles Spring from the first controller? so when generating the request this bean contains data.

I need change the bean that handles Spring to generate the new request whit this data.

Thanks for the help. If there is something you do not understand I will try to explain it better.

Answer (score 0):

I did not quite understand what you are looking for, from your statement - The first time the bean that handles spring is object empty. - I guess you would be hitting a null pointer or exception says that the session attribute is null.

Usually, when you declare anything as session attribute e.g. **@SessionAttributes("salarioBean")**, then on submission or the very first time when the portlet is rendered, the framework assumes that the session attribute is already created and available in session.

In order to get rid of the issue - The first time the bean that handles spring is object empty. - all you would need to make sure is to have the attribute already available. For this you can add a method which creates a model attribute using the annotation **@ModelAttribute** e.g. in your case it would be

```
@ModelAttribute("salarioBean")
public SalarioBean getSalarioBean(){
    return new SalarioBean();
}
```

What happens is that when a method is annotated with @ModelAttribute, it is always called before render/action method is invoked everytime and sets the attribute in the Model object so that it is available. However, when the same attribute (e.g. "salarioBean") is also set in the @SessionAttribute, it would be set in the session as soon as it is created and the **further calls to the getSalarioBean() will not be triggered** before render/action method is invoked and is always available in the session.

Hope it helps.